# Use of the word 'encroaching'

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, verbs

I want to say in a formal way that *protecting something without changing it in a bad way is difficult*.

I tried to use the word encroaching but I am unsure about how to use it. Is this the correct way?

> Protecting a program from attackers without encroaching on its
>   behavior is notoriously difficult.

Comment: You want a word somewhere between 'make worse' (accurate, but sounds weak) and 'cripple' (sounds strong, but the meaning is far too severe). 'Attenuate' and 'diminish' don't really work.

Comment: *without encroaching on its behavior* sounds fine to me. The figurative use of "encroach" is very common.

Comment: I think ***encroach*** generally carries strong allusions to both "trespassing" and "trampling over the right of others", so perhaps *le mot juste* here is actually ***impinge*** (with connotations of *impact, adversely affect*). See [Merriam-Webster's exploration](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/infringe-encroach-impinge-usage-difference) of the difference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think trespassing and trampling is what is intended in a figurative sense: The OP does not want the program affected adversely.by something "trespassing and trampling".

Comment: The intended use is for a research paper, we do not often rely on figurative terms.

Comment: so just use a "non-figurative" term, such as aforementioned ***adversely affect***

Comment: @FumbleFingers `Adversarly affect` sounds good, but the answer with `impair` is shorter and seems to the point.

Comment: true, but if we're to believe [this NGram,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=without+adversely+affecting+performance%2Cwithout+impairing+performance&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwithout%20adversely%20affecting%20performance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwithout%20impairing%20performance%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwithout%20adversely%20affecting%20performance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwithout%20impairing%20performance%3B%2Cc0) ***adversely affecting*** is the new kid on the block that seems to be winning out in the popularity stakes! :)

Comment: This is a fair argument, but my goal is to give the maximum information with the fewest possible words. :)

Comment: 'Behavior' here is a broadened sense that could be argued to be metaphorical. Not that I feel that that's an argument against using it here, but perhaps 'performance' fits better (though originally, again, human-orientated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb "to impair" confers the idea of damaging or simply making less effective and can be used.

> (SOED) **1** *v.t.* Make less effective or weaker; devalue; damage, injure. [from] Middle English.

- Protecting a program from attackers without impairing its behavior is notoriously difficult.

Comment: It's certainly the _mot juste_. But even here, a dictionary definition would make the answer look more polished.